# How to tell electronNET which project to start

Tags: c#, electron, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0, electron.net

I built an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application in a `.sln` with a Windows service. The two projects work in tandem for my business need.

I'm trying to create an Electron app out of the MVC project for easier end user experience. I added the requisite items to my `program.cs` and ran `electronize init`; everything seems to have run correctly, I have my `electron.manifest.json` file. But when I try to run `electronize start`, I get the following error:

> Start Electron Desktop Application... Arguments:
>
> dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c "Debug" --output
> "C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\repo\project\MVCproject\obj\Host\bin"
> /p:PublishReadyToRun=true /p:PublishSingleFile=true
> --no-self-contained MSBuild version 17.6.3+07e294721 for .NET MSBUILD : error MSB1011: Specify which project or solution file to use because
> this folder contains more than one project or solution file.
>
> Error occurred during dotnet publish: 1

Answer (score 0):

Found i need to convert the other projection to a class library while running my electron build or start.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).